# I am trying to override Yoast breadcrumbs using the PHP $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']but am getting an index error

Tags: php, breadcrumbs, http-referer, yoast

I am getting an undefined array error. The goal here is to override the second link to simply go back one page. An example is

> Custom Templates > Category > Template

I added the following code to hijack the breadcrumb structure. Yoast kept adding /blog into the url, and this is a custom post type. My hack is working, however I am getting an error on the server:

> PHP Warning: Undefined array key "HTTP_REFERER"

```php
add_filter('wpseo_breadcrumb_links', 'wpse_332125_breadcrumbs');
function wpse_332125_breadcrumbs($links) {
    if(is_singular('custom-template')) {
        $links[2] = array(
            'text' => 'Category',
            'url' => $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],
            'allow_html' => 2
        );
    }
    return $links;
}
```

Comment: Populating `HTTP_REFERER` is highly dependent on the web server. It could also appear as `HTTP_REFERRER`. What debugging have you done? A `var_dump($_SERVER)` should tell you all you need to know

Comment: `HTTP_REFERER` is sent by the browser (if it's sent at all) and may be manipulated by the user or dropped by the server. Thus, HTTP_REFERER may be inaccurate, actively hostile, or simply absent, and cannot be relied on. Whatever you're doing with it requires significant validation, such that you might do better to find another way.

Comment: This really doesn't make much sense to begin with. Assume I arrived on the page where you intended to put this, directly from a search engine result page. Then the referrer would be that search engine result page. That clicking a link on your site, that has the text "Category", takes me _outside_ of your site, and back to the search engine result page, is probably completely contrary to what most users would expect to happen.

Answer (score 0):

The `Referer` HTTP request header is supplied by browser. It's trivial to forge, but it can also point to a third-party web site that links to yours. Some tools (browser extensions, firewalls...) strip it altogether for security/privacy reasons. And you can't always trust on intermediate proxies to pass on the header.

Said that... If you want to use it, you need to cover several cases:

- Header is missing entirely
- Value does not contain a properly formatted full absolute URL
- URL belongs to an external site
- User does not actually come from that URL

These points aren't hard to deal with from a technical standpoint (you have [isset()](https://php.net/isset), [parse_url()](https://php.net/parse_url), [str_starts_with()](https://php.net/str_starts_with)...), but some of them they require making some decisions regarding functionality and security.

Possible alternatives to replace or complement this:

- Keep track of visited pages yourself in server-side storage (session, database...). This is reliable and flexible, but may not play nice with multi-tab browsing.
- Make it a client-side feature and implement it with JavaScript, using data from browser history (e.g. [tabs.goBack()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/goBack)).
- Do nothing, and educate users to use browser's *Back* button. In my experience, this is something that most users are typically familiar with.